# Executable file cannot be downloaded or copied to computer

Tags: windows-8.1, file-transfer, anti-virus

Today, I tried to install a [patch for a game](https://cncnet.org/yuris-revenge) on my Windows 8.1 computer.

However, when I try to download, the connection is immediately interrupted. When I try to download the file on another computer, and copy it using an USB drive, the file gets deleted as soon as I try to execute it.

It sounds like some antivir running havoc, but the computer has no antivirus software other than Windows Defender installed.

How could I find the cause of that issue?

Comment: Can you provide a direct link to the patch file in question?  Have you checked Defender's logs to see if it's blocking it or not?

Comment: It sounds like, Windows Defender, is actively protecting your system.  Disable it and see if the same behavior happens.

Comment: @Techie007: The page providing the mentioned patch is linked above. I did not want to deep-link the exe file directly.